# Reattempt conflict resolution during git rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I'm in the middle of a very large rebase, resolving conflicts as I go and using `git rebase --continue.`

Part way trying to resolve conflicts on multiple files, I realise I've made a bit of a mess of it. Is there an easy way I can go back to this stage of the rebase, before I started resolving conflicts?

Obviously I don't want to use `git rebase --abort` and lose all of the time that I've spent fixing other conflicts.

I found the following Stack Overflow question, but could do with some clearer steps:

[How to rollback a single conflict resolution during git rebase](//stackoverflow.com/questions/33306335/how-to-rollback-a-single-conflict-resolution-during-git-rebase)

In particular, what does the `-m` flag do? Is `path/to/wrong` the name of the branch that I'm rebasing onto, the the branch that I'm rebasing or a reference to a particular commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset a single file to the un-merged version, do:

```
git checkout --merge path/to/file
```

If you know the commit hash for the original version of the commit that is currently being applied (if not, look in the reflog), you can automate the process for all files changed in that commit:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(git show --pretty=format: --name-only 812b091)
do
  git checkout --merge "$file"
done
```

From the `git-checkout` man page:

> `-m, --merge`
>
> [snip]
>
> When checking out paths from the index, this option lets you recreate the conflicted merge in the specified paths.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I managed to run the bash script you suggested, but got the following errors:
`error: path 'src/ConfigLoader.py' does not have all necessary versions
error: pathspec 'src/config/default-config(actual).json' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'src/config/default-config.json' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'src/config/personal-words-list.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'src/config/user-config.json' did not match any file(s) known to git.`